# Use Raspberry Pi 4B as wifi access point and wifi client at same time to function as an extender/repeater

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-2

Looked at older threads and found that none of them were working properly and was hoping for an updated tutorial. My main issue is that my Model 3 won't connect to a certain wifi network, and was hoping to be able to use the Pi to work as an access point to provide internet to it.

Edit: The wifi I am attempting to connect to is a school wifi network with no password. There is a captive portal but any devices which have their Mac addresses registered are able to bypass the portal. I previously bypassed the portal for my pi but am having issues with connecting my model 3 to the wifi, as the range of the car for connecting seems to be poor, hence why I am here. I am attempting to extend the wifi network from the pi to my model 3 to connect to.

I have previously gone through this tutorial: [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge)

but found that after doing so, internet was broken on my pi, with an error saying dhcpc could not be reached. All I am trying to do is extend the wifi for the car to connect to.

The pi is currently broadcasting its own access point, but doesn't seem to want to connect to the current wifi as well so that it has something to pull internet from.

Comment: Welcome.  *"Looked at older threads and found that none of them were working properly and was hoping for..."* -> The problem with this kind of question is that it begs other people to waste their time regurgitating things you have already tried.  Instead, you need to be specific about exactly what you have tried and where it went wrong.  *"main issue is that my Model 3 won't connect to a certain wifi network"* -> Meaning the question begins to read as an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479).  Again, you need to focus on the details of the issue.

Comment: @goldilocks Better to mark it [Duplicate] with [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/89803/79866).

Comment: I went ahead and added to the original post to give more information, I think that this case is somewhat unique and should not be marked duplicate.

Comment: What is dhcpc? What car you are talking about? Have you registered the mac address of your RasPi to the network?